# Why we need RPC programming?

Tags: sockets, rpc

I work on system security and i want to know why we need the RPC programming and what is the differences between RPC and simple socket programming? Both of them have a client and server application,tcp/ip based,IP address,port number ,...
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RPC is one definition of how to send structured data as a call to the server and get structured data as a response back. You could use any of [a wide variety of protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call#Other_RPC_analogues) with the same basic goal, like SOAP or WCF.

Any of those protocols builds on top of TCP/IP, and lets the server and the client communicate using predefined strucures. You could do the same without any of those protocols, but then you would have to set up a new set of custom rules for how the server and client should communicate.

You don't need any of those protocols for communication, and sometimes (in realtime online gaming for example) a custom streamlined protocol is used instead, but for most client-server communication a well known protocol is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a lot of different RPC technologies, so it is hard to say what you are refering to. But generally speaking it is a layer on top of network transports (like UDP and TCP) to marshall parameters and call results. You need it to communicate in a structured way with services. Some commonly used applications and system services use well known RPC mechanisms (like Windows DCOM, NFS mount protocol, Kerberos, SAP RFC).